# Why does GetSendEndpoint require absolute uri instead of just a name of the queue?

Tags: masstransit

IBusControl.GetSendEndpoint() requires absolute uri, whereas it should already have all sufficient information because bus is already configured:

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
{
    sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
    {
        h.Username("guest");
        h.Password("guest");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it allows you to send to any host or vhost. Publish uses the configured endpoint, and is what we expect you to be using most of the time. Direct sends are needed sometimes but introduce coupling - one of the things messaging is supposed to reduce.

Comment: Do I get it write that publishing should be used both for Events and Commands?

Comment: Yup. Both commands and events could have multiple consumers in the future. By sending you are limiting that ability.

Comment: But this makes no sense, commands are meant to be deliver once. If I have two worker processes reading commands from a Send then I'm gaurenteed to only have each command delivered/processed once. If I used publish for commands then any subscriber can read every message and I'll get duplicate processing..... unless I've really missed something in MassTransit

Comment: @matt_lethargic Absolutely true. Sending and Publishing are two distinct concepts.

Comment: @Travis  If you read MT Docs, you will encounter this information: Commands should NOT be published.